# Does ALTER TRIGGER also enable a disabled trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Just experienced something really strange (to me anyway) with SQL Server and a triggers. Details follow - unsure which are relevant so I'll just list (if I missed anything, please do ask):

- type of trigger: `INSTEAD OF INSERT`
- it is the only trigger on the Table
- Database in question was copied (from an existing db) which **had** the trigger - I did not perform this copy (so I don't know what method was used to do it).
- the copied database table now has new columns, with constraints - most, if not all, of which are just NOT NULL
- the trigger was never ALTERED until after I did - it **did not** account for the new columns with the constraints

Ok so here goes: It seems that the trigger NEVER was invoked until I **ALTERED** it (and started causing issues all of which are "expected behavior" now that I can see what's going on).

- because the (new) DB Table has new columns with NOT NULL constraints *and* the original trigger (INSERT) didn't account for this, INSERT fails **as expected**
- however, prior to my ALTERING the trigger, INSERTs **succeeded**!! Again, note that this trigger didn't account for the new columns...even my ALTER still didn't account for them (my error) - so it's not as if I "corrected" anything by my ALTER action. However, the difference in result/behavior, before (INSERTs succeed which is **unexpected**) and after my ALTER TRIGGER (INSERT fails as **expected**) is perplexing....

I have not been able to find any resource that says to the effect that *ALTERING* a trigger will "enable it" - assuming it was disabled - which is the only way I can make sense of it all...

So it seems there is something about database copy(ing) that has to do with triggers? Why would (or rather would) an `ALTER` trigger suddenly bring a trigger back to life (without explicitly `ENABLE`-ing it)?

I'm by no means a DBA nor a SQL guru, so if it's obvious, I'm ok with being put in the hall of shame....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I couldn't find it in the documentation either, but it appears that `ALTER`ing a trigger does indeed enable it:

```
create table dbo.t (col1 int)
go

create trigger tr on dbo.t instead of insert as insert into dbo.t values(1)
go

disable trigger tr on dbo.t
go

-- returns 1
select is_disabled from sys.triggers where parent_id = object_id('dbo.t')
go

alter trigger tr on dbo.t instead of insert as insert into dbo.t values(2)
go

-- now returns 0
select is_disabled from sys.triggers where parent_id = object_id('dbo.t')
go

drop table dbo.t
go
```

I assume that explains the behaviour you're seeing. If I had to take a complete guess, I'd say that `ALTER TRIGGER` is (transactional) syntactic sugar for `DROP TRIGGER` followed by `CREATE TRIGGER` so the trigger is re-enabled because it's actually re-created but this is pure speculation.

Comment: Thank you for your effort above - it's illustrates things for me (and everyone else who happens on this thread) - speculation or not :)

Comment: [It will be added to the documentation](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/781722/alter-trigger-implicitly-enables-a-disabled-trigger). I don't think your complete guess is correct though. `create_date` remains the same which wouldn't happen if it was dropped and created.

Comment: @MartinSmith That's why it was a complete guess :) I didn't look into the rest of the trigger metadata so I didn't notice that the create date hadn't changed.